# Java - Transform Json structure

Tags: java, arrays, json

I am a novice in Java and I am looking a way to transform Json like in this is  example.

I do not know json array, mapper or use List will be more useful for me

Here is the example:

Document received:

```
 {   
        "data1": "A", 
        "data2": "B", 
        "data3": "C", 
        "data4": [{ 
                       "subdata": [{ 
                                       "subsubdata": "mam" 
                       }, 
                       { 
                                       "subsubdata": "mom" 
                       }, 
                       { 
                                       "subsubdata": "mim" 
                       }] 
        } 
    }
```

Document transformed:

```
 { //data  transformed
                    "data1": "A", 
                    "data2": "B", 
                    "data3": "C", 
                    "data4": { 
                                   "subdata": { 
                                                   "subsubdata": "mam" 
                                   } 
                    } 
    }, 
    { 
                    "data1": "A", 
                    "data2": "B", 
                    "data3": "C", 
                    "data4": { 
                                   "subdata": { 
                                                   { 
                                                                   "subsubdata": "mom" 
                                                   } 
                                   } 
                    } 
    }, 
    { 
                    "data1": "A", 
                    "data2": "B", 
                    "data3": "C", 
                    "data4": { 
                                   "subdata": { 
                                                   { 
                                                                   "subsubdata": "mim" 
                                                   } 
                                   } 
                    } 
    }
```

Comment: The input json is invalid. You have an opening bracket on line 5 but no corresponding closing bracket.

Answer (score 1):

Give a try to Jackson.

With the `ObjectMapper` class you can transform a Json in a nested `Map<String, Object>` collection.

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
TypeReference<Map<String,Object>> typeRef = new TypeReference<Map<String,Object>>() {};
Map<String, Object> rs = mapper.readValue(myJsonString, typeRef);
```

Comment: Thanks !!, is there some examples which have be done in order to see how to manage to do it , in a good way?

Comment: Thanks !!, I willl try to  start with it